# Problem with countDocuments Mongoose: its not actually waiting for the callback function to execute

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose

I've a problem with a Mongoose backend. i guess its an asynchronous problem. Can someone try to explain me how countDocuments works?

```
    albumFields.features = [];
    for await (const feature of features) {
      await Artist.countDocuments({ _id: feature._id }, (err, count) => {
        if (count > 0) {
          albumFields.features.push({ _id: feature._id });
        }
        console.log('artist.count', albumFields.features);
      });
      console.log('features.forEach', albumFields.features);
    }
    console.log('!!!', albumFields.features);
```

the output im getting is:

```
artist.count [ { _id: '5ec09f9c99339f3ad85973c0' } ]
features.forEach [ { _id: '5ec09f9c99339f3ad85973c0' } ]
features.forEach  [ { _id: '5ec09f9c99339f3ad85973c0' } ]
!!! [ { _id: '5ec09f9c99339f3ad85973c0' } ]
artist.count [ { _id: '5ec09f9c99339f3ad85973c0' },
  { _id: '5ec09fb199339f3ad85973c4' } ]
```

The output i would expect is:

```
artist.count [ { _id: '5ec09f9c99339f3ad85973c0' } ]
features.forEach [ { _id: '5ec09f9c99339f3ad85973c0' } ]
artist.count [ { _id: '5ec09f9c99339f3ad85973c0' },
  { _id: '5ec09fb199339f3ad85973c4' } ]
features.forEach [ { _id: '5ec09f9c99339f3ad85973c0' },
  { _id: '5ec09fb199339f3ad85973c4' } ]
!!! [ { _id: '5ec09f9c99339f3ad85973c0' },
  { _id: '5ec09fb199339f3ad85973c4' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is countDocuments() will return a promise only if there is no call back function. In our case we created the callback which gets the number of documents matching the filter.

I am not sure why the code executed the way it did so maybe someone can explain but I did manage to solve the problem.

```
    let arraytest = [];
    for (const feature of features) {
      await Artist.countDocuments({ _id: feature._id }).then((count) => {
        if (count > 0) {
          albumFields.features = [
            ...albumFields.features,
            { _id: feature._id },
          ];
        }
      });
    }
```

For anyone else who runs into the same problem, there was a link on the mongoose documentation which is easy to miss.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#countDocuments